# How can I use authorize when accessed via window.postmessage in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, postmessage

It seems window.postmessage that don't support authorization using username and password.  ([See](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage))

How can I authorize in postmessage like XMLHTTPRequest().open() meethod.([See](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open-method))

Thanks.

Comment: Not. `postMessage` is used to pass messages to **existing frames/windows**. It does not initiate a new request to the server.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Is there any way to authorize using postMessage not against cross-origin-pricy.

Comment: `postMessage` must specify a `targetOrigin` parameter. When the target frame does not match this parameter, the message is not received. The `onmessage` event receives an `origin` property. You can use this value to see if the origin is allowed to make requests. When you have control over both pages, you might be able to implement a kind of authorization.